# PostgreSQL: Do regclass/oid columns persist across backups?

Tags: postgresql, backup, restore, postgresql-9.6, regclass

I have a large table (audit) in which I store relation ID of the schema and table.
This is conveniently populated by trigger using TG_RELID.
It is also convenient because I can index it and the index would be smaller than if I were to store "schema"(text) and "table"(text) columns separately and index them.
Also, I can then do queries using `WHERE relation_id = 'myschema:mytable'::regclass` and it just works.

My question is if this is "safe" to do in terms of backup/restore (will the schema.table have the same regclass/oid in target server and it did in the source server?

Any other issue I should be aware of?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I wouldn't rely on the specific values of OIDs to be portable *at all*. Even if you try it and you find it to work with the current version of PostgreSQL, it might *not* do so in newer releases.

If you backup your database in a source machine and try to restore it on a different machine (or, in general, another [PostgreSQL Database Cluster](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/creating-cluster.html)) that does already have other databases, schemas, etc. it is very likely that the different OIDs your source database was using are already used to represent other different things in the target database.

The `schema_name.table_name` correspondence to an OID is handled by PostgreSQL within its system tables. If you need equivalent functionality, with *the guarantee it behaves the way you need it to* and not *the way PostgreSQL uses its internal OIDs*, I'd recommend you actually duplicate this behaviour with a `your_tables` table, where you store an arbitrary `id` (a serial) and `schema_name`, `table_name`. This way, your database is safe to backup and restore, and you're likely to avoid modifications for any newer postgreSQL version.

You may need an extra lookup in your trigger(s), but might save you a lot of trouble in the future.

Comment: Your answer is only accurate if a raw `oid` type is used for the column type. When one of its aliases (like `regclass`) is used, the dump will contain the qualified (and quoted, if necessary) name of identifier of the object, which makes sense, since `pg_dump` has to rely on the `output_function` (i.e., cast to `text`) of each type it dumps.

Answer (score 2):

The contrib module `pg_stat_statements` uses OIDs to fingerprint queries. So, the stability guarantees you'll get by doing this yourself are essentially the same as the documented guarantees for that module.

It sounds like you're talking about stability when using `pg_dump`. There is no guarantees around stability there. Only for physical backups.

Answer (score 2):

Whether or not a OID persists across backups depends on whether you use a “raw” `oid` type or one of its subcatalog-specific aliases. The reason has everything to do with the fact that when you cast `oid` to `text`, what you get is … text, whereas, when you cast, for example, `regclass` to `text`, you get a valid identifier (quoted if necessary, and schema-qualified if the schema with the `oid`/`regclass` is not part of the `search_path`).

Here's a little demo:

```sql
create table table_meta (
    tbl regclass
        primary key
    ,a_meta_datum bool
        not null
        default true
);

create table tbl1 (int int);
create table tbl2 (bla text);

insert into table_meta
    (tbl, a_meta_datum)
values
    ('tbl1', default)
    ,('tbl2', false)
;
```

And here's the relevant part of the dump [edited for brevity]:

```sql
CREATE TABLE public.table_meta (
    tbl regclass NOT NULL,
    a_meta_datum boolean DEFAULT true NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE public.tbl1 (
    "int" integer
);

CREATE TABLE public.tbl2 (
    bla text
);

COPY public.table_meta (tbl, a_meta_datum) FROM stdin;
public.tbl1 t
public.tbl2 f
\.
```

As you can see, what is present in the dump is not the raw `oid`, but the `text` representation that is appropriate for the OID alias (`regclass`) that I used.

Though this is good news, I'm somewhat saddened that I find this out only now, after finally more extensively testing this for myself, and only after I already modified some of my extensions to *also* have `some_relation_name`-type columns instead of just a `some_relation regclass` column.

See https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-oid.html for an overview of the available OID aliases and their general behavior.